# How can I achieve this hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I am currently reverse building this website, everything else works ok, however,I cannot find a way to achieve the photo hover effect like it does.

http://www.lovelytemplates.com/viewdemo/Snaps

And here is my code, can anyone advise me where did I do wrong?

```css
img {
  width: 236px;
  height: 314px;
}
div:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://demo.graphpaperpress.com/snaps/files/2013/04/child-72305-480x640.jpg" alt="" />asdfasdf asd
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try? I didn't look at how the original site did it. Quite possibly there's a better way:

```css
img {
  width: 236px;
  height: 314px;
  position: absolute;
}

div.overlay {
  width: 236px;
  height: 314px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  line-height: 314px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

div.container:hover div.overlay {
  width: 236px;
  height: 314px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://demo.graphpaperpress.com/snaps/files/2013/04/child-72305-480x640.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="overlay">
    Text goes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woah! Awesome dude. We both answered at the same time... `:D`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it this way. I have used a combination of:

- `opacity`
- `translateY`
- `position`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 236px;
  height: 314px;
  opacity: .8
}
div:hover img,
div:hover .caption {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  right: 0; left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

.caption span {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0; left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://demo.graphpaperpress.com/snaps/files/2013/04/child-72305-480x640.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="caption"><span>Hello World</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for exact same effect on hover

```
.title {
    font-size: 8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 7px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

    .title :hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```